# How to avoid a product in Neo4J Cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Neo4J Cypher query:

```
MATCH (u:User{uid:'1819228'}), 
(ctx:Context)-[:BY]->(u) 
WITH DISTINCT ctx, u 
MATCH (s:Statement)-[:IN]->(ctx), 
(s)-[:BY]->(u) 
RETURN DISTINCT s, ctx 
ORDER BY s.timestamp ASC;
```

I have a feeling that something here is not efficient, because it runs pretty slow. Is it a case of creating a product with several query results?

What would be the best way to optimize this query to get the results in the same form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be faster (and you may not need the `DISTINCT`):

```
MATCH (u:User)<-[:BY]-(s:Statement)-[:IN]->(ctx:Context)-[:BY]->(u)
WHERE u.uid = '1819228'
RETURN DISTINCT s, ctx 
ORDER BY s.timestamp;
```

You may also want to create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) (or [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/schema/#cypher-intro-constraints), which automatically creates an index) on `:User(uuid)`, which will quickly find the desired `User` to start off the query.

Comment: Thank you! The index is set up, it's because I have too many records with `s` that it takes so long. Do you know if there's any difference using `u.uid` or `(u:User{uid:'id'})`?

Comment: The 2 syntaxes have an identical result. The latter syntax was, at least at one point, deprecated. But I can not find that documented anywhere anymore, so that may not be true any more.

Comment: By the way, I found that the first query is actually faster because I have multiple :BY connections for ctx to u in my database, so it limits the number of iterations that have to be made.